# cucumber stepdef matching multiple regex arguments

Tags: gherkin, cucumber-junit

I am trying to write a step def that matches multiple String values with double quotes:

```
When I have a HeaderUtil
Then header is generated with fields matching patterns 
"""
"\"%s\":\"%s\""
""" 
or
"""
"\"%s\":%s"
"""
```

This stepdef will see that the serialized fields match one of the above patterns  in the generated string.

I am looking to have a stepdefinition that will have two arguments that matches one or the other pattern.
Currently, I am getting a parser error:

```
Caused by: gherkin.lexer.LexingError: Lexing error on line 8: '""" \
"""
"\"%s\":%s"
"""
```

Is there a way more than one multiline parameter can be passed in a step definition?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's referenced to this topic of [Cucumber Documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber-expressions/#) and [Custom parameter types](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber-expressions/#custom-parameter-types)

**Custom parameter types**

You can define custom parameter types to represent types from your own domain. Doing this has the following benefits:
Automatic conversion to custom types
Document and evolve your ubiquitous domain language
Enforce certain patterns
Imagine we want a parameter to match the colors **red**, **blue** or **yellow** (but nothing else). Let's assume a `Color` class is already defined. This is how we would define a custom color parameter type:

```
parameterTypeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
    "color",                                  // name
    "red|blue|yellow",                        // regexp
    Color.class,                              // type
    new SingleTransformer<>(new Function<String, Color>() {
        @Override
        public Color apply(String s) {
            return new Color(s);
        }
    }), // transform
    false,                                    // useForSnippets
    false                                     // preferForRegexpMatch));
```

Comment: ....then please copy the relevant parts into your answer. Otherwise, if the documentation changes or gets removed, your answer might get useless